# AzureRm Runbook passing multiple arguments to CustomScriptExtension-PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure

I have an Azure Automation Runbook that collects multiple Parameters during execution.  These are stored for the following Section:

```
Set-AzureRmVMCustomScriptExtension -ResourceGroupName $VMResourceGroupName `
    -VMName $VMName `
    -Location $Location `
    -ContainerName $ContainerName `
    -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName `
    -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey `
    -FileName $FileName `
    -Run $FileName `
    -Argument $StorageAccountKey,$Az_Client_Name,$Az_Disk_Drive,$Az_Dest_ShareName,$Az_Dest_Path `
    -Name $ScriptExtensionName
```

The error I am receiving is the following:

*Starting Script Extension...*
Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Argument'. Specified method is not 
supported.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException

This error only occurs when multiple items are being passed in the -Argument line of the script.  If I only pass a single Argument, the error goes away.
I am sure it's a matter of formatting, but commas, spaces, commas-and-spaces, nothing seems to work correctly.

edit: It was pointed out that this was a duplicate question.  Fantastic.  The solution presented in the other article does not work for me.  The solution was to use a single space between Arguments with quotes around them all.  This does not work as none of the Arguments are being passed, but the error listed above does not appear anymore.

**Actual Answer:**
I checked the page that claimed to have the answer already - it was from 2017 and Azure has indeed changed since then.
What I was able to do in order to actually solve this problem was as follows...

Added 
$params = "-arg1 $arg1 -arg2 $arg2 -arg3 $arg3"

Then in the -Argument line, I simply replaced what I had with 
-Argument $params

Then in the script that was being pulled down to the VM in -FileName I had to add a Param section:
param(
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, HelpMessage = "some text here")]
     [String]$arg1
     )

That was the actual solution to the question asked

Comment: Pass them all as one space delimited string. Having said that, the question is a dupe.

Comment: It is easy to just say "this is a duplicate of xxxx" without actually answering the issue.

Comment: That is how the site works. If the question has already been asked and answered, then it is marked as a duplicate. I even went the extra step of adding a comment to tell you what I expected the issue is. If you think this is not a duplicate, you should explain that as you did and the question gets reopened if sufficient people agree that it is not a duplicate.